# PJSIP codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]

Tags: android, h.264, pjsip, pjsua2

I have developed a softphone app to allow my user to communicate with the door station (with video integrated), everything is fine if i dial from my app to the door station, i have audio, i have video.
But when i dial from door station to my app, i am receiving this problem and no video show on the app, i am getting following error message, but i don't really understand what this error message stands for

Error Message:
**vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]**

Does anyone know what is this error for?

I have put all my SDP Trace at the bottom.(Due to character limitation, i had cut down some of the negotiation step)

SDP and Android Stack Trace(Without IP and Project name):

```
    INVITE sip:1101@<app-ip-address>:6000;ob SIP/2.0
       Via: SIP/2.0/UDP <server-ip-address>:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj31873378-f709-43db-b590-b10ebcf5f9a1
       From: "Sunway Vivaldi" <sip:9998@<server-ip-address>>;tag=fb189e53-15f4-4e4d-9193-609f347997dc
       To: <sip:1101@<app-ip-address>:5060;ob>
       Contact: <sip:asterisk@<server-ip-address>:5060>
       Call-ID: 6a4297b1-5600-4206-bcb6-c55c3614c3e5
       CSeq: 27304 INVITE
       Allow: OPTIONS, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, PRACK, REGISTER, MESSAGE, REFER
       Supported: 100rel, timer, replaces, norefersub
       Session-Expires: 1800
       Min-SE: 90
       P-Asserted-Identity: "Sunway Vivaldi" <sip:9998@<server-ip-address>>
       Max-Forwards: 70
       User-Agent: FPBX-13.0.190.17(13.14.0)
       Content-Type: application/sdp
       Content-Length:   325

       v=0
       o=- 1445287161 1445287161 IN IP4 <server-ip-address>
       s=Asterisk
       c=IN IP4 <server-ip-address>
       t=0 0
       m=audio 12626 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
       a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
       a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
       a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
       a=fmtp:101 0-16
       a=ptime:20
       a=maxptime:150
       a=sendrecv
       m=video 15022 RTP/AVP 99
       a=rtpmap:99 H264/90000
       a=sendrecv

       --end msg--
09-07 16:49:07.207  SVC-BIND_SERVICE handled : 0 / 
09-07 16:49:10.610 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.610   pjsua_call.c !Answering call 0: code=200
09-07 16:49:10.610 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.610  pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: deinitializing media..
09-07 16:49:10.610 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.610  pjsua_media.c  ..Call 0: cleaning up provisional media, prov_med_cnt=2, med_cnt=0
09-07 16:49:10.610 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.610        icetp00  ..Stopping ICE, reason=media stop requested
09-07 16:49:10.611 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.611  pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: initializing media..
09-07 16:49:10.611 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.611        icetp00  ..Creating ICE stream transport with 2 component(s)
09-07 16:49:10.652 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.652        icetp00  ...Comp 1/0: host candidate <app-ip-address>:35513 (tpid=64) added
09-07 16:49:10.691 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.691        icetp00  ...Comp 2/0: host candidate <app-ip-address>:54370 (tpid=64) added
09-07 16:49:10.691 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.691        icetp00  ...ICE stream transport 0xab3aa4d4 created
09-07 16:49:10.793 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.793        icetp01  ..Creating ICE stream transport with 2 component(s)
09-07 16:49:10.832 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.831        icetp01  ...Comp 1/0: host candidate <app-ip-address>:46015 (tpid=64) added
09-07 16:49:10.871 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.871        icetp01  ...Comp 2/0: host candidate <app-ip-address>:45768 (tpid=64) added
09-07 16:49:10.871 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.871        icetp01  ...ICE stream transport 0xab380ff4 created
09-07 16:49:10.934 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.934  pjsua_media.c  ..Media index 0 selected for audio call 0
09-07 16:49:10.934 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.934        icetp00  ..ICE session created, comp_cnt=2, role is Controlling agent
09-07 16:49:10.934 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.934        icetp00  ..ICE nomination type set to aggressive
09-07 16:49:10.934 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.934        icetp00  ..Candidate 0 added: comp_id=1, type=host, foundation=Hc0a80177, addr=<app-ip-address>:35513, base=<app-ip-address>:35513, prio=0x7effffff (2130706431)
09-07 16:49:10.934 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.934        icetp00  ..Candidate 1 added: comp_id=2, type=host, foundation=Hc0a80177, addr=<app-ip-address>:54370, base=<app-ip-address>:54370, prio=0x7efffffe (2130706430)
09-07 16:49:10.934 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.934        icetp01  ..ICE session created, comp_cnt=2, role is Controlling agent
09-07 16:49:10.934 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.934        icetp01  ..ICE nomination type set to aggressive
09-07 16:49:10.935 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.934        icetp01  ..Candidate 0 added: comp_id=1, type=host, foundation=Hc0a80177, addr=<app-ip-address>:46015, base=<app-ip-address>:46015, prio=0x7effffff (2130706431)
09-07 16:49:10.935 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.935        icetp01  ..Candidate 1 added: comp_id=2, type=host, foundation=Hc0a80177, addr=<app-ip-address>:45768, base=<app-ip-address>:45768, prio=0x7efffffe (2130706430)
09-07 16:49:10.935 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.935  pjsua_media.c  ...Call 0: updating media..
09-07 16:49:10.935 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.935        icetp00  ....Stopping ICE, reason=Remote answer doesn't support ICE
09-07 16:49:10.935 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.935        icetp00  ....Destroying ICE session 0xab2ea6f4
09-07 16:49:10.935 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.935    pjsua_aud.c  ....Audio channel update..
09-07 16:49:10.935 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.935 strm0xab46bb34  .....VAD temporarily disabled
09-07 16:49:10.936 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.936 strm0xab46bb34  .....Encoder stream started
09-07 16:49:10.936 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.936 strm0xab46bb34  .....Decoder stream started
09-07 16:49:10.936 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.936  pjsua_media.c  ....Audio updated, stream #0: PCMU (sendrecv)
09-07 16:49:10.936 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.936        icetp01  ....Stopping ICE, reason=Remote answer doesn't support ICE
09-07 16:49:10.936 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.936        icetp01  ....Destroying ICE session 0xab3c8e04
09-07 16:49:10.936 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.936    pjsua_vid.c  ....Video channel update..
09-07 16:49:10.945 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.945 vstenc0xab4699  .....Encoder stream started
09-07 16:49:10.945 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.945 vstdec0xab4699  .....Decoder stream started
09-07 16:49:10.945 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.945    pjsua_vid.c  .....Setting up RX..
09-07 16:49:10.945 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.945    pjsua_vid.c  ......Creating video window: type=stream, cap_id=-1, rend_id=0
09-07 16:49:10.946 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.945     vid_port.c  .......Opening device OpenGL renderer [OpenGL] for render: format=I420, size=352x288 @22:1 fps
09-07 16:49:10.946 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.946 android_opengl  .......Re-initializing OpenGL due to format change
09-07 16:49:10.946 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.946 android_opengl  .......Android OpenGL ES renderer successfully created
09-07 16:49:10.946 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.946     vid_port.c  .......Device OpenGL renderer [OpenGL] opened: format=I420, size=352x288 @22:1 fps
09-07 16:49:10.946 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.946    pjsua_vid.c  .......stream window id 0 created for cap_dev=-1 rend_dev=0
09-07 16:49:10.946 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.946    pjsua_vid.c  .......Window 0 created
09-07 16:49:10.946 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.946 android_opengl  ......Starting Android opengl stream
09-07 16:49:10.947 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.946    pjsua_vid.c  .....Setting up TX..
09-07 16:49:10.947 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.947    pjsua_vid.c  ......Creating video window: type=preview, cap_id=1, rend_id=0
09-07 16:49:10.947 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.947     vid_port.c  .......Opening device Front camera [Android] for capture: format=I420, size=176x144 @15:1 fps
09-07 16:49:10.949 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.949     vid_port.c  .......Device Front camera [Android] opened: format=I420, size=176x144 @15:1 fps
09-07 16:49:10.950 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.950     vid_port.c  .......Opening device OpenGL renderer [OpenGL] for render: format=I420, size=176x144 @15:1 fps
09-07 16:49:10.950 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.950 android_opengl  .......Re-initializing OpenGL due to format change
09-07 16:49:10.950 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.950 android_opengl  .......Android OpenGL ES renderer successfully created
09-07 16:49:10.950 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.950     vid_port.c  .......Device OpenGL renderer [OpenGL] opened: format=I420, size=176x144 @15:1 fps
09-07 16:49:10.950 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.950    pjsua_vid.c  .......preview window id 1 created for cap_dev=1 rend_dev=0
09-07 16:49:10.950 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.950    pjsua_vid.c  .......Window 1 created
09-07 16:49:10.950 26929-26986/ : 16:49:10.950  android_dev.c  ......Starting Android camera stream
09-07 16:49:11.477 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.477  pjsua_media.c  ....Video updated, stream #1: H264 (sendrecv)
09-07 16:49:11.485 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.484    pjsua_aud.c  ...Conf connect: 0 --> 1
09-07 16:49:11.485 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.485    pjsua_aud.c  ....Set sound device: capture=-1, playback=-2
09-07 16:49:11.485 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.485    pjsua_aud.c  .....Opening sound device (speaker + mic) PCM@16000/1/20ms
09-07 16:49:11.485 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.485   opensl_dev.c  ......Creating OpenSL stream
09-07 16:49:11.497 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.497  echo_webrtc.c  ......WebRTC AEC successfully created with options 3
09-07 16:49:11.497 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.497   ec0xab523e30  ......WebRTC AEC created, clock_rate=16000, channel=1, samples per frame=320, tail length=30 ms, latency=100 ms
09-07 16:49:11.497 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.497   opensl_dev.c  ......Starting OpenSL stream..
09-07 16:49:11.505 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.505   opensl_dev.c  ......OpenSL stream started
09-07 16:49:11.505 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.505   conference.c  ....Port 0 (OpenSL ES Audio) transmitting to port 1 (sip:9998@<server-ip-address>)
09-07 16:49:11.506 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.506    pjsua_aud.c !...Conf connect: 1 --> 0
09-07 16:49:11.506 26929-27272/ : 16:49:11.505   Master/sound !Underflow, buf_cnt=0, will generate 1 frame
09-07 16:49:11.509 26929-27272/ : 16:49:11.508   Master/sound !Underflow, buf_cnt=0, will generate 1 frame
09-07 16:49:11.510 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.509   conference.c !....Port 1 (sip:9998@<server-ip-address>) transmitting to port 0 (OpenSL ES Audio)
09-07 16:49:11.511 26929-27272/ : 16:49:11.510   Master/sound !Underflow, buf_cnt=0, will generate 1 frame
09-07 16:49:11.512 26929-27272/ : 16:49:11.512   Master/sound  Underflow, buf_cnt=0, will generate 1 frame
09-07 16:49:11.515 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.515   pjsua_core.c !....TX 1151 bytes Response msg 200/INVITE/cseq=27304 (tdta0xab1c25d0) to UDP <server-ip-address>:5060:
   SIP/2.0 200 OK
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP <server-ip-address>:5060;rport=5060;received=<server-ip-address>;branch=z9hG4bKPj31873378-f709-43db-b590-b10ebcf5f9a1
   Call-ID: 6a4297b1-5600-4206-bcb6-c55c3614c3e5
   From: "Sunway Vivaldi" <sip:9998@<server-ip-address>>;tag=fb189e53-15f4-4e4d-9193-609f347997dc
   To: <sip:1101@<app-ip-address>;ob>;tag=768822bd-fbc8-4303-b73f-217332a87620
   CSeq: 27304 INVITE
   Contact: <sip:1101@<app-ip-address>:6000;ob>;+sip.ice
   Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
   Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
   Session-Expires: 1800;refresher=uac
   Require: timer
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Content-Length:   473

   v=0
   o=- 3713762946 3713762947 IN IP4 <app-ip-address>
   s=pjmedia
   b=AS:352
   t=0 0
   a=X-nat:0
   m=audio 41965 RTP/AVP 0 101
   c=IN IP4 <app-ip-address>
   b=TIAS:64000
   a=rtcp:56984 IN IP4 <app-ip-address>
   a=sendrecv
   a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-16
   m=video 49049 RTP/AVP 99
   c=IN IP4 <app-ip-address>
   b=TIAS:256000
   a=rtcp:43723 IN IP4 <app-ip-address>
   a=sendrecv
   a=rtpmap:99 H264/90000
   a=fmtp:99 profile-level-id=42000a; packetization-mode=0

                                                                           --end msg--
09-07 16:49:11.521 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.521     vid_util.c  Orientation converter created: 176x144 to 144x120, maintain aspect ratio=yes
09-07 16:49:11.521 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.521  android_dev.c  Video capture orientation set to 4

09-07 16:49:11.589 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.589 android_opengl !Re-initializing OpenGL with native window 0xab382df8: success
09-07 16:49:11.596 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.595 os_core_unix.c  Info: possibly re-registering existing thread
09-07 16:49:11.631 26929-26986/ : 16:49:11.630 android_opengl !Re-initializing OpenGL with native window 0xab56aaa8: success
09-07 16:49:11.710 26929-27272/ : 16:49:11.709   ec0xab523e30  Buffer size adjusted from 2240 to 1761 (eff_cnt=1440)
09-07 16:49:11.741 26929-27272/ : 16:49:11.740   ec0xab523e30  Buffer size adjusted from 2401 to 1922 (eff_cnt=1440)
09-07 16:49:11.768 26929-27272/ : 16:49:11.767   ec0xab523e30  Buffer size adjusted from 1922 to 1443 (eff_cnt=1440)

09-07 16:49:12.060 26929-27272/ : 16:49:12.059 strm0xab46bb34 !VAD re-enabled
09-07 16:49:12.219 26929-26994/ : 16:49:12.218  pjsua_media.c !Sending video keyframe request via SIP INFO
09-07 16:49:12.221 26929-26994/ : 16:49:12.220   pjsua_call.c  Call 0 sending INFO request..

09-07 16:49:12.338 26929-27272/ : 16:49:12.338   ec0xab523e30 !Buffer size adjusted from 1763 to 1284 (eff_cnt=1440)
09-07 16:49:12.365 26929-27272/ : 16:49:12.363   Master/sound  Underflow, buf_cnt=0, will generate 1 frame
09-07 16:49:12.465 : 16:49:12.465 vstdec0xab4699 !codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:12.485 26929-27273/ : 16:49:12.484   ec0xab523e30 !Underflow, buf_cnt=4, will generate 1 frame

09-07 16:49:12.500 26929-27273/ : 16:49:12.499   ec0xab523e30 !Underflow, buf_cnt=4, will generate 1 frame
09-07 16:49:13.597 26929-27234/ : 16:49:13.596 vstdec0xab4699 !codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.164 : 16:49:14.163 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.196 : 16:49:14.194 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.226 : 16:49:14.225 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.252 : 16:49:14.252 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.313 : 16:49:14.312 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.347 : 16:49:14.346 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.372 : 16:49:14.372 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.435 : 16:49:14.434 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.480 : 16:49:14.479 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.529 : 16:49:14.528 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.559 : 16:49:14.558 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.592 : 16:49:14.591 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.621 : 16:49:14.619 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.676 : 16:49:14.674 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.708 : 16:49:14.707 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.736 26929-27272/ : 16:49:14.734   Master/sound !Underflow, buf_cnt=202, will generate 1 frame
09-07 16:49:14.757 : 16:49:14.756 vstdec0xab4699 !codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.808 : 16:49:14.807 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.833 : 16:49:14.832 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:14.857 26929-27272/ : 16:49:14.853   Master/sound !Underflow, buf_cnt=202, will generate 1 frame

09-07 16:49:16.332 26929-26986/ : 16:49:16.328   pjsua_call.c !Call 0 hanging up: code=603..
09-07 16:49:16.333 26929-26986/ : 16:49:16.333   pjsua_core.c  ....TX 441 bytes Request msg BYE/cseq=26007 (tdta0xab582018) to UDP <server-ip-address>:5060:
   BYE sip:asterisk@<server-ip-address>:5060 SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP <app-ip-address>:6000;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj08ea8b8b-51c0-4193-a5e9-0f83e57794d6
   Max-Forwards: 70
   From: <sip:1101@<app-ip-address>;ob>;tag=768822bd-fbc8-4303-b73f-217332a87620
   To: "Sunway Vivaldi" <sip:9998@<server-ip-address>>;tag=fb189e53-15f4-4e4d-9193-609f347997dc
   Call-ID: 6a4297b1-5600-4206-bcb6-c55c3614c3e5
   CSeq: 26007 BYE
   User-Agent: Pjsua2 Android 2.6
   Content-Length:  0


                                                                           --end msg--
09-07 16:49:16.509 : 16:49:16.508 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:16.534 : 16:49:16.533 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:16.591 : 16:49:16.590 vstdec0xab4699  codec decode() error: Codec frame is too short (PJMEDIA_CODEC_EFRMTOOSHORT) [err:220082]
09-07 16:49:16.601 : 16:49:16.601   pjsua_core.c  .RX 430 bytes Response msg 200/BYE/cseq=26007 (rdata0xab3410bc) from UDP <server-ip-address>:5060:
       SIP/2.0 200 OK
       Via: SIP/2.0/UDP <app-ip-address>:6000;rport=6000;received=<app-ip-address>;branch=z9hG4bKPj08ea8b8b-51c0-4193-a5e9-0f83e57794d6
       Call-ID: 6a4297b1-5600-4206-bcb6-c55c3614c3e5
       From: <sip:1101@<app-ip-address>:5060;ob>;tag=768822bd-fbc8-4303-b73f-217332a87620
       To: "Sunway Vivaldi" <sip:9998@<server-ip-address>>;tag=fb189e53-15f4-4e4d-9193-609f347997dc
       CSeq: 26007 BYE
       Server: FPBX-13.0.190.17(13.14.0)
       Content-Length:  0


                                                                           --end msg--
09-07 16:49:16.604 : 16:49:16.603  pjsua_media.c  .....Call 0: deinitializing media..
09-07 16:49:16.604 : 16:49:16.604  pjsua_media.c  .......Media stream call00:0 is destroyed
09-07 16:49:16.605 : 16:49:16.604    pjsua_vid.c  .......Stopping video stream..
09-07 16:49:16.611 : 16:49:16.611  android_dev.c  ........Stopping Android camera stream
09-07 16:49:16.980  SVC-UNBIND_SERVICE handled : 0 / BindServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@17924814 intent=Intent { cmp=/.intercom.IntercomSipService }}
09-07 16:49:16.834 : 16:49:16.834    pjsua_vid.c  ........Window 1: destroying..
09-07 16:49:16.835 : 16:49:16.834  android_dev.c  .........Stopping Android camera stream
09-07 16:49:16.836 : 16:49:16.835     vid_port.c  .........Closing Front camera..
09-07 16:49:16.836 : 16:49:16.836  android_dev.c  .........Android camera stream destroyed
09-07 16:49:16.837 : 16:49:16.836 android_opengl  .........Stopping Android opengl stream
09-07 16:49:16.837 : 16:49:16.837     vid_port.c  .........Closing OpenGL renderer..
09-07 16:49:16.838 : 16:49:16.837 android_opengl  .........Stopping Android opengl stream
09-07 16:49:16.856 : 16:49:16.855 android_opengl  ........Stopping Android opengl stream
09-07 16:49:16.856 : 16:49:16.856    pjsua_vid.c  ........Window 0: destroying..
09-07 16:49:16.857 : 16:49:16.856 android_opengl  .........Stopping Android opengl stream
09-07 16:49:16.857 : 16:49:16.857     vid_port.c  .........Closing OpenGL renderer..
09-07 16:49:16.857 : 16:49:16.857 android_opengl  .........Stopping Android opengl stream
09-07 16:49:16.873 : 16:49:16.872  pjsua_media.c  .......Media stream call00:1 is destroyed
09-07 16:49:16.874 : 16:49:16.873        icetp00  ......Stopping ICE, reason=media stop requested
09-07 16:49:16.874 : 16:49:16.874        icetp00  .......ICE stream transport 0xab3aa4d4 destroyed
09-07 16:49:16.875 : 16:49:16.874  ice_session.c  .......ICE session 0xab2ea6f4 destroyed
09-07 16:49:16.876 : 16:49:16.875        icetp01  ......Stopping ICE, reason=media stop requested
09-07 16:49:16.876 : 16:49:16.876        icetp01  .......ICE stream transport 0xab380ff4 destroyed
09-07 16:49:16.877 : 16:49:16.876  ice_session.c  .......ICE session 0xab3c8e04 destroyed
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this response is too late. I've suffered same problem recently the way I solved the problem is increase buffer size.

If you read the document from here https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Video_Users_Guide#modvcodec you can see what parameters you need to setup for encoding/decoding.

Here is my example for Android.

```
String codecId = "H264";

VidCodecParam param = new VidCodecParam()
// Sending 1280 x 720.
param.getEncFmt().setWidth(1280);
param.getEncFmt().setHeight(720);

// Sending @30fps.
param.getEncFmt().setFpsNum(30);
param.getEncFmt().setFpsDenum(1);

// Bitrate range preferred: 512-2048kbps.
param.getEncFmt().setAvgBps(512000);
param.getEncFmt().setMaxBps(2048000);

// Buffer size for decode frame
param.getDecFmt().setWidth(2048);
param.getDecFmt().setHeight(1080);

App.getInstance().getEndpoint().setVideoCodecParam(codecId, param);
```